# Битрикс Хлебные крошки

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день. Такая проблема. Использую компонент bitrix:catalog. В шаблоне сайта вывожу хлебные крошки. Сейчас, когда я нахожусь на странице самого элемента каталога, то цепочка такая: *Главная - Поролон оптом - Поролон для мебели*. Поролон для мебели это название раздела, а сам элемент называется Вязкий. Значит цепочка должны быть такая.  *Главная - Поролон оптом - Поролон для мебели - Вязкий*. Но мне нужно получить такую(без названия раздела)  *Главная - Поролон оптом - Вязкий*. PS Если добавить в шаблон элемента

```
<?=$APPLICATION->AddChainItem($arResult["NAME"], “”);?>,
```

то будет: *Главная - Поролон оптом - Вязкий - Поролон для мебели*

Comment: Название вопроса должно быть содержательным, а не состоять из меток.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно просто убрать название раздела, снимите галочку в параметрах компонента "Включать раздел в цепочку навигации".

Если же нужно переместить название элемента в конец, то разместите ваш вызов $APPLICATION->AddChainItem после компонента, который добавляет раздел в цепочку.

Comment: В данном комоненте нет такой настройки. Я знаю про нее.

Comment: Действительно, даже удивили, у "catalog" нет. Но она есть у некомплексного "catalog.element", по русски это выглядит так: "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "N". Можете прописать в файле element.php шаблона компонента "catalog"